# How do I append the ids of all anchors in the document into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this code

```
<body>
<a id="id_1">Link1</a>
<a id="id_2">Link2</a>
<a id="id_3">Link3</a></body>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

How do I create an array containing id1, id2, id3 using jQuery?

thank you

Comment: Those aren't [links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#links). For an A element to be a link, must have an HREF attribute.

Answer (score 6):

```
var idArray=$('a').map(function(){
  return this.id;
}).get()
```

The `map()` method will return the array wrapped as a jQuery object. Using `get()` unwraps it from jQuery returning a native array

Comment: You should also filter out anchors, since they aren't links but will be returned by an 'A' selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$("a").each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier in plain js:

```
function getLinkIds() {
    var ids = [], links = document.links, i = links.length;
    while (i--) ids[i] = links[i].id;
    return ids;
}
```

Note that this will only get link ids, anything based on A tags will also return targets, which are not links.